# How to properly design a database for rating system with multiple rating criterias

Tags: sql, django, database, sqlite

I am doing rating system on my current django project and I need to implement database for rating. Database would be simple, if I didn't have multiple rating criteries, now I have to ask:

How would you design a database with these objects:
User
RatedObject
Rating

there will ofcourse be multiple users and objects to be rated AND multiple rating criterias.

Now my current idea would be to go for few separate tables with each of the objects such as:

```
USER(pk=id, fk= rating.id)
RATED_OBJECT(pk=id, fk= rating.id, overall_attribute_1, overall_attribute_2, overall_rating)
RATING(pk=user.id, pk=rated_object.id, fk=rated_attribute1, fk=rated_attribute2)
RATED_ATRIBUTE(pk=id, fk=type, value)
TYPE(pk=id, name) - 2 types since we have 2 attributes to be rated
```

(now overal_rating will be average of all overall attributes and each overal attribute will be average of all attributes of one type from ratings, where the id of rated object will be same)

I have a bad feeling about doing this 'multiple-FK-to-one-PK' operation. Would it make more sence to make table for each rated attribute? Or maybe say **** it and have values in the RATING itself and screw RATED_ATTRIBUTE and TYPE table? What do you guys think?

EDIT: IF my guess was right- meaning I could connect RATING with RATED_ATTRIBUTE multiple times (multiple fk to 1 pk), I need to set constraints, so when rating happens, it all goes to fields of RATING correctly
(when rating attribute one, in RATING i need to ensure that in RATED_ATTRIBUTE the type is exactly the one like in RATING). Now, I cannot get my head arround, how to do that whidj Django's CheckConstraint, any ideas?
snippet:

```
class RatedAttribute(models.Model):
    TYPE = (
        ('attribute1', 'attribute1'),
        ('attribute2', 'attribute2'),

    )

    id      = models.IntegerField(primary_key= True, auto_created=True)
    type    = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=TYPE, default=None)
    value   = models.IntegerField()


class Rating(models.Model):
    user_id           = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='RatingUser')
    rated_object_id   = models.ManyToManyField(RatedObject, through='Rating_Object')

    attribute1  = models.ForeignKey(RatedAttribute, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    attribute2  = models.ForeignKey(RatedAttribute, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            CheckConstraint(
                *NO IDEA HOW TO FILL THIS CONSTRAINT(s)*, name='something')
        ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.place
```

code is with proper connecting *Rating_Object*

Comment: So your problem is that you want to have multiple types of ratings?

Comment: Yes, user will be able to rate rated_attribute1 and rated_attribute2 for this example. so far i thought of connecting RATING table with RATED_ATTRIBUTE multiple times with constraint to the type of attribute, so it is correctly connected.

Comment: Can you give an example. cause all that is running in my head is like: 1 star , 2 stars, 3 stars, etc.

Comment: Ok, will try :) :

For example we could rate object FOOD right. now, for example, rated attribute1 could be TASTE, rated attribute 2 could be SMELL.

so user will be able to rate TASTE and SMELL. After user-rating happens (and yes, it could be 1-5 stars), another sql queries happens and i will compute overal ratings (avg of each taste and smell from all users and then overal rating = avg of overal ratings of each attribute) for certain FOOD object. Now, the queries for computing avg ratings is not the issue, the issue is implementing the database co I can do these operations :)

Comment: So your current problem is not the rating but the product. From what I understood is that there are many different types of products and one standard of rating would not apply to every product?

Comment: It is the rating. the parameters to be rated are same every time. I have problem with implementing database with multiple rating criterias (such as said - taste and smell)

Answer (score 0):

This is what i came up with after reading what you put in the comments.

If anything comment on this answer.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.
rating_choices = [
        (1, '1 Star'),
        (2, '2 Stars'),
        (3, '3 Stars'),
        (4, '4 Stars'),
        (5, '5 Stars'),
]

class Product(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Product"
        verbose_name_plural = "Products"

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Rating(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "rating"
        verbose_name_plural = "ratings"

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name=_(""), on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="rating")
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, verbose_name=_(""), on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="product_rating")
    taste = models.IntegerField(choices=rating_choices)
    smell = models.IntegerField(choices=rating_choices)    
    def __str__(self):
        return "{self.user.username}'s rating for {self.product.name}"
```

Comment: This is how I guessed it should not be done, since when you are creating a database by NF rules, you should not have TASTE and SMELL in the same table as RATING,since you can easily decompose it to its own table, right? Even better, you can make table TYPE_OF_RATING with possible values of mentioned taste and smell and values 1-5. what do you think? Or you see no problem with taste and smell having in table rating from the view of database implementation?

Comment: @Nuwanda Making another model just for taste and smell would just make you have to query multiple different models just to get the ratings from 1 product. In my example since taste and smell are in the same rating model you only query the ratings model and the user and product if needed